How do get Android Auto coordinates labels to work?
When I add coordinates in Android Auto, ( near my house in North Carolina ) the hey Google navigate to coordinate label ID sends me to another state over 1,000 miles away?  Why doesn't it go to the coordinates in North Carolina?
Mike
I tried renaming the label ID.

Google Maps typically accepts coordinates in decimal degrees (35.7796, -78.6382) or degrees, minutes, and seconds (35°46'46.56"N 78°38'17.52"W). Are the coordinates in the correct format?

Yes.  How can I attach an image here?

I have determined that the voice command through my phone works fine, but when I use the voice command through my Android Auto Amtifo A28 device, it takes me to a location over 1,000 miles away?
